# How to say $\{S\} \in X$ in first order set theory? That is, without using $\{,\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

How do I say $\{S\} \in X$ in first order set theory? That is, without using $\{,\}$? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

$$\exists Y:(Y\in X\wedge \forall Z:(Z\in Y\leftrightarrow Z=S))$$

Or a bit shorter using bounded quantifiers:

$$\exists Y\in X:\forall Z:(Z\in Y\leftrightarrow Z=S)$$

Comment: Or alternatively $\forall Y(\forall Z(Z=Y\leftrightarrow Z=S)\to Y\in X)$.

Comment: I think $Z=Y$ is typo for $Z\in Y$ @HenningMakholm

Comment: @bof: Oops, yes. Too late to edit.